# Apache segmentation fault on local server but not on vps

Tags: php, apache

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on my laptop and on my vps and both have php 5.4.4 + apache setup. The same php code causes segmentation fault on my local server but runs fine on my vps (checked the logs .. no segmentation fault error yet). I also tried running the project with php's server and it also crashed with a segmentation fault.

And not just this, several times, the code runs (say 1 in 10) but most of the times i get a segfault error. Please help

Comment: you should check the log and your php.ini settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was arising due to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62358 .. I removed all trait usage and set up an inheritance tree for all the functionality that traits provided(sigh .. i loved using traits though) and everything worked fine . This bug has been fixed in newer versions of php but for some reason the fix hasn't been merged into 5.4.4 yet. And since i chose the lazy way of setting up php using ppa, i am stuck with 5.4.4 till the guy managing the ppa updates it